# Speed up sample function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sample

In a quite big data frame, I have to pick up some random rows to execute a function. In my example, the first function I use is the variance and then a function closed to the real one I use in my script, called after `f`. I do not detail the purpose of `f` but it deals with truncated Gaussian distribution and maximum-likelihood estimation.

My problem is that my code is way too slow with the second function and I suppose a bit of optimization of the `for loop` or the `sample` function could help me.

Here is the code :

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,2e+6,2))
df$V1 <- runif(nrow(df),0,1)
df$V2 <- sample(c(1:10),nrow(df), replace=TRUE)

nb.perm <- 100 # number of permutations
res <- c()
for(i in 1:nb.perm) res <- rbind(res,tapply(df[sample(1:nrow(df)),"V1"],df$V2,var))

library(truncnorm)
f <- function(d) # d is a vector
{

f2 <- function(x) -sum(log(dtruncnorm(d, a=0, b=1, mean = x[1], sd = x[2])))
  res <- optim(par=c(mean(d),sd(d)),fn=f2)
  if(res$convergence!=0) warning("Optimization has not converged")
  return(list(res1=res$par[1],res2=res$par[2]^2))
}

for(i in 1:nb.perm) res2 <- rbind(res,tapply(df[sample(1:nrow(df)),"V1"],df$V2,function(x) f(x)$res2))
```

I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: It's probably the optimization in `optim` that is slow. But to be sure you could profile your code. If it is `optim`, you could try different optimization algorithms to speed up your code. I do not think that `sample` is the bottleneck. A side remark: this is also not the bottleneck, but using `res=rbind(res,new data)` is not very efficient. Rather preallocate some vector `res=rep(NA_real_,nb.perm)` and fill it element-wise.

Comment: Indeed the `rbind` way was not the right thing to do. Building an empty matrix (or vector) and then fill it is more efficient. Thank you for that. It improves the code efficiency, but it's still quite long.